# How do I parse the output of a command into columns using awk and grep

Tags: awk, solaris, ksh

I have the output of `pkginfo -l` that looks like below

```
A: aaa1  
B: bbb1
C: ccc1
D: ddd1

A: aaa2  
B: bbb2
C: ccc2
D: ddd2

A: aaa3  
C: ccc3
D: ddd3
```

I want this output translated into columns such that it looks like below

```
A        B        C         D
aaa1     bbb1     ccc1      ddd1
aaa2     bbb2     ccc2      ddd2
aaa3              ccc3      ddd3
```

Currenlty I am finding names of packages individually using `pkginfo` and then running `pkginfo -l pkgname` to get the output and parse on it to display info in columns but each invocation of `pkginfo -l` is time consuming.

Is there an easier way to do in ksh with grep/awk where I can store teh output of `pkginfo -l` into a file and then use grep/awk on that to achieve the intended output?

Comment: Like I mentioned, currently I am finding names of packages individually using "pkginfo" and then running "pkginfo -l pkgname" for each package which gets me output only pertaining that package which I further parse into columns.

Comment: I think [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61003/data-pivot-with-awk) gives enough clues on how to pivot a table.

Comment: You never need awk AND grep since awk can do anything useful that grep can do. What if "B" was missing from the first record instead of the last? Would you still expect the columns to be ordered A B C D in the output? Whatever the answer - how is the order of columns decided, is it alphabetic ordering or something else? How would the missing entry affect the rows - would there be a gap at the top of the B row or at the bottom of it or something else?

Comment: @Ed Just saw this now. Valid questions all, i was going to have a delimiter like ; or tab and i did that. So, a missing column was taken care of. Order didn't matter though but I did struggle looking at options to see how I can order my output. Would you want to explain your solution with comments in code as to what affects order, how pattern hold and store is working etc, that probably will help many.(including me)

Comment: @Prasoon no but after you look it over with reference to the manual if you have any remaining questions please feel free to ask and I'll be happy to answer them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some to help you get started.

```
awk -F": " 'BEGIN {c=0} NF{a[$1 FS c]=$2;b[$1];next} {c++} END {for (i=0;i<=c;i++) {for (j in b) printf "%s\t",a[j FS i];print ""}}' file
aaa1    bbb1    ccc1    ddd1
aaa2    bbb2    ccc2    ddd2
aaa3            ccc3    ddd3
```

Comment: For some reason, the columnar output was reversed but this was a good help for to start on and I finally achieved the output. Thanks much.

Comment: @Prasoon the "for some reason" is the `in` operator traverses arrays in essential random order. See the awk man page for why.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want depending on the answers to the question I left in a comment:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS="\t" }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,a,/: /)
        name = a[1]
        value = a[2]
        if ( !seen[name]++ ) {
            colNname2nr[name] = ++numCols
            colNr2name[numCols] = name
        }
        colNr = colNname2nr[name]
        cell[NR,colNr] = value
    }
    next
}
END{
    for (colNr=1;colNr<=numCols;colNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", colNr2name[colNr], (colNr<numCols?OFS:ORS)
    }
    for (rowNr=1;rowNr<=NR;rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1;colNr<=numCols;colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", cell[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A       B       C       D
aaa1    bbb1    ccc1    ddd1
aaa2    bbb2    ccc2    ddd2
aaa3            ccc3    ddd3
```

Consider this:

```
$ cat file
A: aaa1
C: ccc1
D: ddd1

A: aaa2
B: bbb2
C: ccc2
D: ddd2

A: aaa3
B: bbb3
C: ccc3
D: ddd3

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A       C       D       B
aaa1    ccc1    ddd1
aaa2    ccc2    ddd2    bbb2
aaa3    ccc3    ddd3    bbb3
```

Is that the desired output? If not, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I was able to run through the solution *based* on Jotne's response below yesterday. I tried your solution and this worked too without issues, out of the box!

Comment: The differences between the 2 are that mine will output the columns in the order they appear in your input while Jotne's will be random and Jotne's solution will add trailing tabs to the end of every line and will not print the headers line you asked for.